# My site name and url are not recognized from my mailers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new at ruby on rails, and I've noticed that when I send an email, my site_name and site_url vars are not being recognized from the mailer files.

In my config.yml file I've got the following:

```
development: &local
    site_name: my site name
    site_url: http://localhost:8282

    company_name: my company name
    admin_email: admin@domain.com

    support_name: askdjaskd Support
    support_email: support@domain.com

production:
  <<: *local

staging:
  <<: *local

test:
  <<: *local
```

And in the mailers I call them the as follows:

```
@body[:url]  = "http://#{Setting.get(:site_url)}/"
```

Do I need to write a require statement at the beginning of the mailers? If not, what am I missing?

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: How are you loading config.yml?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Now you are asking, I don't know if I'm loading it...the thing is that in my website I see those variables working, but it doesn't happen the same from the mailers.

Comment: I just googgled how to load that file, and I found out that I have a ConfigGenerator < Rails::Generator::Base loading it. That class may belong to the base app I'm using. Also, within my initializers(this my be the way you're talking about) I found the load_config file doing this: 

configatron.configure_from_yaml("config/config.yml", :hash => Rails.env)

Comment: Right, so you're using the Configatron gem: http://github.com/markbates/configatron

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it! Instead of `Settings.get(:site_url)`, I'm using `configatron.site_url` and it works!

Thank you!

Brian